# Android row is not getting update

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update the row values with 0 or 1. Here is my update method.Where is wrong with my code .

```
dbhelper.updateStarFlag(actid, strStarFlagMark);

     public boolean updateStarFlag(String str_ActivityId, String str_StarFlag)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = getReadableDatabase();
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(COL_AllPost_PostActivityId, str_ActivityId);
            args.put(COL_AllPost_StarFlag, str_StarFlag);
            int i = db1.update(Table_AllPost_Table, args, COL_AllPost_PostActivityId + "='"+str_ActivityId+"'", null);
            return i > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update something, you need a **writable** database. I changed the query to look a little more like in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update) for `SQLiteDatabase`

```
 public boolean updateStarFlag(String str_ActivityId, String str_StarFlag)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWriteableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(COL_AllPost_PostActivityId, str_ActivityId);
        args.put(COL_AllPost_StarFlag, str_StarFlag);

        int i = db1.update(Table_AllPost_Table, args, COL_AllPost_PostActivityId + "= ? ", new String[]{str_ActivityId});
        return i > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To update something in database, you need writeable database, not just readable.

Change below line:

```
SQLiteDatabase db1 = getReadableDatabase();
```

to :

```
SQLiteDatabase db1 = getWriteableDatabase();
```

Hope, this helps you.